# Access is denied debugging ASP.NET Core app referencing Sqlite running in IIS

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core, sqlite-net

The ASP.NET Core 2.2 project references `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite (2.2.3)` as a `PackageReference`.

Debugging the app in IIS Express works fine, because of the elevated user process.

**Problem:** Debugging the app in IIS throws an error

> Unable to load DLL 'e_sqlite3' or one of its dependencies: Access is denied

How can I debug the app in IIS without laborious publishing steps?

My analysis so far: while `e_sqlite3.dll` is found and loaded successfully in the folder `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages\sqlitepclraw.lib.e_sqlite3.v110_xp\1.1.12\runtimes\win-x64\native\e_sqlite3.dll` it has only `Read` but no `Read & Execute` permission set.

The missing `Execute` permissions seems to be the culprit.

It works if I give `Users` group or `ApplicationPoolIdentity` also `Read & Execute`.

Why is the global NuGet packages folder missing `Read & Execute`? Is this only a problem of the unmanaged code dll's?

**Stack Trace**

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'e_sqlite3' or one of its dependencies: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>
> at SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3.NativeMethods.sqlite3_libversion_number()
>   at SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3.SQLitePCL.ISQLite3Provider.sqlite3_libversion_number()
>   at SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider(ISQLite3Provider imp)

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52397501/nuget-references-to-assemblies-in-runtimes-folder-not-added/52461004#52461004: .NET Core and .NETSTANDARD don't copy dependencies to output directory, they are mapped using deps.json which points to relative paths from local NuGet cache.

Comment: I tryed adding `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>` to the csproj but the runtimes folder wont be copied